# Setting different Fonts for the different states of UIButton

Tags: ios

How can one set different fonts for the different UIbutton states? Thanks for your help on this one.

Answer (score 10):

This is a very cool question, which prompted me to make a subclass of `UIButton` that allows the setting of state fonts!

I also wrote some example code that shows how to set the font. If you are using Interface Builder, then set the class of the button to `ConfigurableButton`. In code, the button must also be declared as `ConfigurableButton`, since I've added new properties, and a `setFont:forState:` method.

*Please leave a comment for any improvements that can be made!*

**View Controller implementation**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ConfigurableButton.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ConfigurableButton *toggleButton;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Set the fonts for button's states
    _toggleButton.normalFont        = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BradleyHandITCTT-Bold" size:14];
    _toggleButton.highlightedFont   = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:14];
    _toggleButton.selectedFont      = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Zapfino" size:14];
    _toggleButton.disabledFont      = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
}

@end
```

**ConfigurableButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

/**
 * A button that allows fonts to be assigned to each of the button's states.
 *
 * A state font can be specified using setFont:forState, or through one of the
 * four state Font properties.
 *
 * If a font is not specified for a given state, then
 * the System font will be displayed with a font size of 15.
 */
@interface ConfigurableButton : UIButton

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIFont *normalFont;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIFont *highlightedFont;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIFont *selectedFont;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIFont *disabledFont;

/**
 * Set a font for a button state.
 *
 * @param font  the font
 * @param state a control state -- can be
 *      UIControlStateNormal
 *      UIControlStateHighlighted
 *      UIControlStateDisabled
 *      UIControlStateSelected
 */
- (void) setFont:(UIFont *)font forState:(NSUInteger)state;

@end
```

**ConfigurableButton.m**

```
#import "ConfigurableButton.h"

@implementation ConfigurableButton

//Sets one of the font properties, depending on which state was passed
- (void) setFont:(UIFont *)font forState:(NSUInteger)state
{
    switch (state) {
        case UIControlStateNormal:
        {
            self.normalFont = font;
            break;
        }

        case UIControlStateHighlighted:
        {
            self.highlightedFont = font;
            break;
        }

        case UIControlStateDisabled:
        {
            self.disabledFont = font;
            break;
        }

        case UIControlStateSelected:
        {
            self.selectedFont = font;
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            self.normalFont = font;
            break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Overrides layoutSubviews in UIView, to set the font for the button's state,
 * before calling [super layoutSubviews].
 */
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    NSUInteger state = self.state;

    switch (state) {
        case UIControlStateNormal:
        {
            [self setTitleFont:_normalFont];
            break;
        }

        case UIControlStateHighlighted:
        {
            [self setTitleFont:_highlightedFont];
            break;
        }

        case UIControlStateDisabled:
        {
            [self setTitleFont:_disabledFont];
            break;
        }

        case UIControlStateSelected:
        {
            [self setTitleFont:_selectedFont];
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            [self setTitleFont:_normalFont];
            break;
        }

    }

    [super layoutSubviews];
}

/**
 * Private
 *
 * Convenience method that falls back to the System font,
 * if no font is configured.
 */
- (void) setTitleFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    if (!font) {
        font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    }

    self.titleLabel.font = font;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution is to set an attributed title for each `UIControl` state:

```
var attributes = [String : AnyObject]()
attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.redColor()
attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)

let normal = NSAttributedString(string: "normal", attributes: attributes)
button.setAttributedTitle(normal, forState: .Normal)

attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.redColor()
attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)

let selected = NSAttributedString(string: "selected", attributes: attributes)
button.setAttributedTitle(selected, forState: .Selected)
```

Comment: Feel Cool Feature in 2019

Answer (score 5):

Usually, I code like this:

```
itemButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "title", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.font(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .medium), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)]), for: .normal)
itemButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "title", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.font(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .medium), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]), for: .selected)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working code block. `IB_DESIGNABLE` is just a tiny improvement to make the results visualizable on the Interface Builder :-)

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton
@end

IB_DESIGNABLE @implementation MyButton
// Here you can override the look & feel for each state
// Actually not only fontSize, but any writable properties ^_^
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
    [super setEnabled:enabled];
    self.titleLabel.font = enabled ? [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    self.titleLabel.font = highlighted ? [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    self.titleLabel.font = selected ? [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14] : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
}

@end
```

You can see designable `MyButton`s font reflected in the interface builder like this
[image]

Comment: @inforeqd Please let me know if this solution works for yo

Answer (score 2):

Just create your custom button. Override layout subviews. Set your required fonts.

```
// Interface
@interface EezyButton : UIButton

@end
//Implementation
#import "EezyButton.h"

@implementation EezyButton

- (void)layoutSubviews{
    if (self.state == UIControlStateNormal) {
        [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    }
    else if (self.state == UIControlStateHighlighted){
        [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]];

    }
    else if (self.state == UIControlStateDisabled){
        [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    }
    else if (self.state == UIControlStateSelected){
        [self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:28]];
    }
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 version with custom font:

```
todayButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "today", attributes: [.font: UIFont(name: "Font-Name", size: 16)!]), for: .normal)

todayButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "today", attributes: [.font: UIFont(name: "Font-Name", size: 24!]), for: .selected)
```

Don't forget to set button type Custom in Interface Builder if you use it

Answer (score -1):

You can set font on Design View on for more details:

You can set all this in Interface Builder itself. Unless you have very string reasons to do it in code. Here's how to do it in IB -

Open the right side bar & then click on "State Config", there you see the various states of the button, Default, Highlighted, Selected & Disabled. Now you can set different images for each state, different font type & font colors for each state. Hopr this helps...

[image]

Thanks..!

Comment: I think what Dinesh is trying to say is that you can create an image with a different font and then set the button to that image.

Comment: now iam update answer,you can following image to state config change to combo in uibutton to chage the font for uibutton different states.

Comment: sorry for not being clear earlier.. how can we do that programatically without having to use images... I ask because, i get a text input from a web service that determines what needs to be put on the button for its different states

Comment: You can change the uibutton title or title font?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. They want to "set different fonts for the different UIbutton states" - not images.

Comment: @daidai it says you can set different images, but also "different font type & font colors for each state", and the screenshot (old as it is) seems to agree, no?

Comment: The solution is to overide the button and layout subviews as its question about fonts not images mentioned anywhere.